# How to create MQTT client with node.js?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, mqtt

I'm new with MQTT and want to create MQTT client using node.js which accepts authentication header to connect to MQTT. URL to connect is tcp://ip_address:61616 and needs username and sessionId. [Server uses activeMQ].

Please help me with this.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to write code for you, you have to try and if you get stuck show us what you've done and somebody will help you fix it.

Comment: @hardillb I'm aware that no one will write code for me. I tried so many things and after that I'm asking this question to community. If you can't help than at least don't discourage peoples. Thanks for your valuable time and suggestion.

Comment: If you have tried something then show us what you've tried and we'll help fix it, but as it stands this question show absolutely no indication you have even tried to google or follow some of the many available examples. Also please read the doc on asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried for this for whole 5 days and I can't put all over here.

Comment: @hardillb as stated in my question I'm totally new with mqtt and don't know proper functioning of it as well.

Comment: You have actually enabled MQTT in ActiveMQ? The port you've listed is the default AMQP port which will not work with a MQTT client

Comment: @hardillb sorry, but I only knows that server I'm trying to connect is using ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('tcp://ip_address', {
  port: 61616,
  username: 'myuser',
  clientId: 'myclientid'
})
```

Comment: I tried this bt it not worked. Is there any way by which I can check that I'm hitting right ip address?

Comment: Edited. Added port as separate option.